# DAX Measure to determine % of parent row in column chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been struggling to find a way to achieve the result of a matrix visualization in Power BI, in a line and clustered column chart.

I have tried using ALLSELECTED, ALL, ALLEXCEPT in order to ignore one filter but no matter how I try it, I'm not reaching my end goal.

```
CarCountPerCategory = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[CarID]),
    ALLSELECTED(Table[Filter])
    )
```

This still breaks down the measure to the Filter level instead of ignoring it. I am looking for something that will give me the total distinct count regardless of the Filter column. E.g. TimesReshopped 1 - 190 on all 3 columns, TimesReshopped 2 - 182 on all 3 columns of the Filter Column series. I need this as a sidestep in order to divide the distinct car count to the total distinct car count per times reshopped in order to reach the percentage that I am looking for. (the one in the matrix)

[image]

Can someone help me with some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your data table looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this by using ALLEXCEPT and providing all the filter that I was using:

```
CarCountPerCategory = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[CarID]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[Year],Table[Month],Table[LocationName],Table[CustCode],Table[TimeReshoped])
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[Total Category Count]:=
SUMX ( SUMMARIZE ( Table, Table[TimesReshopped] ), [Count of CarID] )
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I haven't tried and unfortunately I am getting the exact same result. (94, 17 ,79 instead of, 190, 190, 190 for TimeReshopped 1) Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks for the help @RADO.